# Need Advice on Installing AC Unit in Antique Wooden Window Frame

Tags: insulation, air-conditioning, window-frame

I recently purchased a 12x20 outdoor shed where I plan to set up my remote office. The shed is fully insulated on the walls and ceiling but tends to get quite hot, so I've decided to install an air conditioning unit.

I've chosen the Midea U-shaped AC unit my because it is extremely quiet, which is important as I am frequently on work calls and my high quality headset fails to block the sound of my kitchen AC.

This unit is not a typical window unit; it's designed to sit at the bottom of the window and is shaped like a U, allowing the window to open and close onto it and isolating the noise from the compressor to the outside. In any case, I will not be opening and closing this window; it will simply provide a frame for the unit and a barrier to the outside.

To keep costs down, I've purchased an old wooden window frame from a local antique store for $5. It measures 26 wide by 16 tall (the AC needs 22x13 of clearance). The manufacturer of the shed has offered to come out and install this third window for me in the side of the building. The walls are framed with 2 x 6 studs spaced 16” and insulated with rolls of r13 mineral wool (I think).

I figured the old window frame would be fine because the window will be mostly taken up by the AC unit, so the glass or insulating qualities didn't seem as important. I’ve owned this AC unit before and I know it is possible to rig up additional support for the unit should the frame not be sufficient.

What is the best way to approach this installation? Are there special considerations I should take into account given that this is an old wooden window frame? Is this a straightforward window install, or does the age of the frame complicate things? I anticipate it will require extra measures to ensure the weather seal.

[image: window frame and AC unit]

Answer (score 8):

If your only objective is to install this air conditioner in a way that is quiet and well insulated, and if you're literally cutting a hole in your wall for it, why do you need a window at all? Why don't you just install this as if it was an in-wall air conditioner? Cut a hole in the wall big enough to pass half of it through, then replace the piece of wall except for a slit big enough for the bottom. Put all the insulation back. Rebuild the wall around the air conditioner, add some framing to support it.   It will essentially be a mini split.

Answer (score 4):

That's not a window frame.  That's the upper sash of a single- or double-hung window.  Which is a beautiful window system that lends itself nicely to installation of window A/Cs.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c36Q1c2fIpM

As you can see, you're missing *a whole bunch of parts* - but being 200 years old, the patent has run out, and you are free to make this yourself, weights and all.  Lots of companies and hardware stores sell this kit. It's pretty basic stuff except for the intricate stuff on the sashes.  For the other sash, see if the antique store has the other one, or fabricate a single-pane version.

However, to step back and look at the greater problem, I'd like to suggest to forget the window A/C and go with a mini-split heat pump.  It doesn't just A/C, it also heats. So no hokey space heaters needed, no breaker trips from running 2 space heaters, etc.

Comment: Lol. How embarrassing—my thinking I have a window and it’s not even half of one. Thank you for the helpful information. I may be better off simply buying one. 

Regarding your other suggestions, I see your point. The contacts you may not have, however, is that the contacts you may not have clever is that this set up is temporaryThe context I did not share however, is that this set up is temporary. Therefore installing a split unit doesn't make sense at this time.

Comment: If you share the whole context initially it's easier for us to give full answers.

Comment: @LaTwunk That's fine, I just wanted to make sure you knew mini-splits are an option.  Affordable DIY friendly units are quite new.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a whole window there. You have most of the glass, stiles, and rail of a single sash. You'll need the other sash and case to have a complete window. Lead paint will also be a concern. A complete window will also need a sill and casing for installation.

If you're really wedded to this aesthetic, you'll need to look for a complete window, which likely will cost you more to both acquire and install than a modern window. If cost is the primary concern, go look on Craigslist/OfferUp/Facebook for a leftover new window. In particular, ones a few year old often don't meet current energy efficiency standards, so they can't be installed in a house but work great for something like a shed. You will have a much easier time working with it, won't have to think about lead paint, and should still spend less than $100 on the window, possibly a lot less. My local CL has a half dozen double hung wood windows for $50-60 that would be $500+ ordered new, and most of them haven't even been installed.